# laravel JWT returns "error": "Unauthorized" on login

Tags: laravel, jwt

its been about three days and I couldn't solve this issue I have looked everywhere (the documentations, stackoverflow ...etc) but with no luck.

Anyway my problem is that whenever I send a POST request to the login api `localhost:8000/api/auth/login` I always get this error :

```
{
"error": "Unauthorized"
}
```

and here is my request body :

```
{
"email": "demo@demo.demo",
"password": "123321"
}
```

I have followed the official documentations : https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

**Edit 1**

request header (postman) :

`Content-Type: application/json`

Routes :

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

`login` function located in `app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php` :

```
 public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

**Edit 2**
here is the route list :

```
|        | GET|HEAD | /                |      | Closure                                     | web          |
|        | POST     | api/auth/login   |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login   | api          |
|        | POST     | api/auth/logout  |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout  | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | api/auth/me      |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@me      | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | api/auth/refresh |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@refresh | api,auth:api |
```

**Edit 3**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please, add the related code: route definition, the method in the controller, how are you doing the request (body & headers).

Comment: @HCK added the requested info

Comment: did you add the `$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);` in the controller's constructor? Also, when you do `php artisan route:list` what endpoints (with middleware) are listed?

Comment: @HCK yes `$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);` exists in the constructor, I have updated the post with the route list

Comment: And are you sure that the user exist in the database? how are you storing the user?

Comment: @HCK this is the user (by tinker) {#2925
       +"id": 1,
       +"name": "demo",
       +"email": "demo@demo.demo",
       +"email_verified_at": null,
       +"password": "123321",
       +"remember_token": null,
       +"created_at": null,
       +"updated_at": null,
     }

Comment: I think that the error is right there: you are not encrypting the password when storing. Include the code when you store your users.

Comment: @HCK please check the last edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184000/discussion-between-hck-and-keloa).

Comment: @HCK thanks a lot problem solved , I have created the user with tinker and it looks like it didn't hash the password by default and that was the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so my solution was:

1) add an aliases into `app.php`

```
...
'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
```

2)
instead of `auth()->attempt($credentials)..` use

```
use JWTAuth;
use JWTFactory;
...
public function login(){
    ...
    if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt(...
```

3) Do not forget to update the other parts, like this one `'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL()` to

```
...
'expires_in' => JWTFactory::getTTL() * 60
```

found the answer here - https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1367#issuecomment-340967334

Answer (score 1):

To me, the solution of the problem is that the auth() expects encrypted passwords to be saved in your database.

So, try to save yours passwords like this:

```
bcrypt($password);
```

Comment: waht.. thanks man... you saved me alot of trouble. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try to set defaults as api in config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you using? Unfortunately, if you are using the **version 8 or higher**, you have to modify api.php as follows:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\{UsersControllers, AuthControllers};

Route::group([
'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
Route::post('refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
Route::post('me', [AuthController::class, 'me']);
});
```

I suggest also to not send data using json, but just as form data, by the way I think that this last one thing is not important so much.

Answer (score -4):

If working with Laravel and Vue uncomment require bootstrap on app.js